# EJB 3 Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin, ejb-3.0

Could you please advise good EJB3 plugin for Eclipse ? What plugins are you using for developing EJB3 in Eclipse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers - it is bundled with WTP tools which have support for EJBs creation. You need to create in Eclipse right type of project (EJB Project) to make use of these tools.

Don't expect to much however, the support is not particularly well developed, as compared to NetBeans for instance (client classes generation, and a few more goodies). On the other hand EJB 3.X does not need much IDE support...